# VM's, virtual networks and my home network

Tags: lan, vmware-workstation

I want to create a small lab of VM's to test out networking with. I have two PC's running VMWare and I need the VM's on these two PC's to be connected to their own LAN.

I am planning on bridging the VM's into my home network. My home network and PC's are in the 192.168.0.0 range, but I want my VM's to be in 10.1.0.0. If I do it this way (Bridging the VM's on both hosts into the network) will the VM's be able to communicate? Will my home router freak out seeing two different subnets?

Is there another, easier way to connect the virtual lan's on two vmware workstations together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I do it this way (Bridging the VM's on both hosts into the network) will the VM's be able to communicate?

They are on the same subnet to each other, yes.

> Will my home router freak out seeing two different subnets?

No, it will forward the packets. Just be aware that your VMs won't be able to communicate with the outside world unless you add a static route, or another network adapter with the same subnet as your router and with your router as the default gateway.